# Error: text search not enabled:- in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-plugins

I get the following error :-

```
[Error: text search not enabled]
```

I am running the folliowing function which is essentially a mongoose-mongodb operation.

```
var textSearch = require('mongoose-text-search');

exports.dbTextSearch = function () {
    console.log('dbTextSearch');
    var gameSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name: String
      , tags: [String]
      , likes: Number
      , created: Date
    });

    gameSchema.plugin(textSearch);

    gameSchema.index({ tags: 'text' });

    var Game = mongoose.model('Game', gameSchema);

    Game.create({ name: 'Super Mario 64', tags: ['nintendo', 'mario', '3d'] }, function (err) {
    Game.textSearch('3d', function (err, output) {
        if (err) return console.log(err); // this outputs the error.
        var inspect = require('util').inspect;
      console.log(inspect(output, { depth: null }));
        });
    });
}
```

I am trying to implement the [mongoose-text-search](https://npmjs.org/package/mongoose-text-search) plugin

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing plugins for mongoose - getting error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513040/installing-plugins-for-mongoose-getting-error)

Comment: If you search for that error string, it's quite simple to find the most likely reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>MongoDB Text search is still an experimental feature. That's why it is disabled by default and [must be enabled manually](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-text-search/). You can do so by either starting mongod with the command line parameter `--setParameter textSearchEnabled=true` or adding the line `textSearchEnabled=true` to the file mongodb.conf.</strike>

Please note that as an experimental feature, text search should not be used in a production environment yet.

**UPDATE**

As of version `2.6` of mongoDB text search feature has production-quality and is enabled automatically.

Answer (score 16):

In MongoDB 2.4 - to enable the experimental text search, use

`setParameter=textSearchEnabled=true`

The following line didn't work for me in the mongodb.conf file.

`textSearchEnabled=true`

**EDIT** In MongoDB 2.6 + it is enabled by default. You just need to set up your text indexes.

Comment: I upgraded my MongoDB to 2.6 and I still got "MongoError: text search not enabled". Is there any way to check whether textSearchEnabled is true or false?

Comment: [textSearchEnabled is deprecated since 2.6](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/parameters/#param.textSearchEnabled). Perhaps that is why it is showing up as not enabled. Not sure how you check. TextSearch works differently (as of 2.6), with the `$text` operator returning multiple docs, rather than `text` returning just the one docs (of docs) in 2.4. Also, check your `version()` in the mongoshell.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify this startup parameter (mentioned in above answers) when you start mongo. So if you start manually, then use:

```
mongod --setParameter textSearchEnabled=true
```

Otherwise, if mongo is deamonized, put it into deamon script. Something like this:

```
start()
{
  echo -n $"Starting mongod: "
  daemon --user "$MONGO_USER" $NUMACTL $mongod --setParameter textSearchEnabled=true $OPTIONS
```

Then you create text index and check it's existence:

```
db.mycoll.createIndex( { someFieldName: "text" } );
db.mycoll.getIndexes()
```